# App directory.listFiles() returns null

Tags: android

I'm trying to access a directory programmatically but `listFiles()` returns null even though I have files in that directory. I created the directory to the app root using `mkdir` command and I pushed images to the directory using `adb push` command. All other directories of the app can be accessed and `listFiles()` returns null only on the directory I made.

App directories (all others directories content, except for pics, is shown by `listFiles()`):

```
dex
inbox
pics
right
```

I have included the needed permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Method that goes through the directories (when the recursion reaches pics directory `root.listFiles() = null`:

```
HashMap<File, Bitmap> imageReader(File root) {
    HashMap<File, Bitmap> returnList = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<File, Bitmap> holderList;

    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            holderList = imageReader(files[i]);
            returnList.putAll(holderList);
        } else {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg") || files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                returnList.put(files[i], getFileBitmap(files[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

EDIT: the UID and GID are same for all the directories

```
root@generic_x86:/data/user/0/com.erkki.hellogridview/files/instant-run #
ls -n
-rw------- 10058    10058           5 2016-07-25 15:56 active
drwx------ 10058    10058             2016-07-25 15:38 dex
drwxrwxrwx 10058    10058             2016-07-25 15:56 inbox
drwxrwxrwx 10058    10058             2016-07-26 13:08 pics
drwxr--r-- 10058    10058             2016-07-26 15:18 pics2
drwx------ 10058    10058             2016-07-25 15:56 right
```

Comment: Edited UID and GID info to the question

Comment: Update: Still no answer found to this question